# Enabling Screen-Recording API in Catalina (kCGWindowName)

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-catalina, screen-recording

The following code worked fine in Mojave .

```
let options = CGWindowListOption(arrayLiteral: CGWindowListOption.excludeDesktopElements, CGWindowListOption.optionOnScreenOnly, CGWindowListOption.optionOnScreenAboveWindow)
let windowList = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(options, kCGNullWindowID) as NSArray? as? [[String: AnyObject]]

for entry  in windowList!
{ let name = (entry[kCGWindowName as String] != nil) ? entry[kCGWindowName as String] as! String : ""
  ...
```

In Catalina

```
entry[kCGWindowName as String]
```

always is nil

In SO: [Detecting screen recording settings on macOS Catalina](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56597221/detecting-screen-recording-settings-on-macos-catalina/58991936#58991936) I read, that is´t required to enable the "screen recording API" an how to detect, if it's enabled.

Unfortunately I do not find out, how to enable the "screen recording API".

As mentioned in SO: [macOS Catalina screen recording permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59197213/macos-catalina-screen-recording-permission) I switched on Automatic Code Signing.

In the System Preferences I see no "+" to add an App, to grant "screen recording".

How can the API Permission for Screen Recording be granted?

Comment: My situation is different, as I'm using javascript via nodejs, but I feel it's relevant. I'm experiencing the same issue with null window names. You can check out the code here: https://github.com/karaggeorge/mac-screen-capture-permissions, which ultimately enabled me to request screen recording permissions in catalina. My app now has screen recording permissions, but still cannot get window names.

Comment: I take it back! I had an unrelated bug. I can confirm that getting window names works with permission and fails without it.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/701/?time=930

Answer (score 5):

This a low level api to request access to screen recording. Calling this functions will present a prompt to give access for screen recording.

```swift
/* Requests event listening access if absent, potentially prompting */
@available(macOS 10.15, *)
public func CGRequestScreenCaptureAccess() -> Bool
```

Comment: Please note @available(macOS 10.15, *) is not correct. It's crashing on Catalina. Available on Big Sur only

Answer (score 2):

You need to call any Screen Record API function. For example screenshot:

```
(void)showScreenRecordingPrompt {
  /*
   macos 10.14 and lower do not require screen recording permission 
   to get window titles 
  */
  if(@available(macos 10.15, *)) {
    /*
     To minimize the intrusion just make a 1px image of the upper left corner
     This way there is no real possibilty to access any private data
    */
    CGImageRef screenshot = CGWindowListCreateImage(
        CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1),
        kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly,
        kCGNullWindowID,
        kCGWindowImageDefault);

    CFRelease(screenshot);

}
```

The solution was get from here: https://blog.csdn.net/lovechris00/article/details/96979960